# A linear combination of the E[X] of random variable X

Tags: probability, expectation, means

I don't understand how to calculate the linear combination to find Y from X. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Suppose $Y = (3X − 2)^2$, and $E[X] = 2$, $var(X) = 5$. Find $E[Y ]$.

Comment: Expand $Y$, then consider the definition of $Var(X)$ as $E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$

Comment: $E[X+Y]=EX+EY$. ${}$

Comment: Also $E(aX + bY + c) = aE(X) + bE(Y) + c,$  where $a, b, c$ are numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Comments of @HarryAlli and @copper.hat give very good clues.

I will show key clues for working a similar problem: finding $E(V),$ where $V = (3X + 1)^2.$

$$E(V) = E[(3X + 1)^2] = \cdots = 9E(X^2) + 6E(X) + 1.$$
You know $E(X)$ and need $E(X^2).$ For that, consider
$$ 5 = Var(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2 = E(X^2) - 4.$$

Something similar works for your problem.